# go run/build hanging

Tags: go, go-sqlite3

I have this simple go file called `main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "mydb.db")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    fmt.Println("Opened Successfully")
}
```

I downloaded the required package but when I try to `go run .` or `go build .` I get nothing, the compiler just seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.
If I remove the line `_ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"` it works as expected with the error message `panic: sql: unknown driver "sqlit3" (forgotten import?)`.

this happens many times with some imported packages.

this is my `go.mod` file:

```
module go-sqlite

go 1.18

require github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.15
```

go version:
`go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64`

Comment: Don’t use filename arguments to go commands. Make sure you have a correct go.mod file.

Comment: What is the reason for that, I just have one go file.

Comment: Because that is how the command works (no where in the docs does it show to use filename arguments). You need to build the package, which is part of a module, not a single file. Go through the “Getting Started” tutorial or “How to Write Go Code”

Comment: Never use go run with filename arguments, especially if you are a novice or having problems.

Comment: Use `-x` to see all commands being executed. Make sure you have a c compiler for the SQLite package and cgo

Comment: It also may help with confusion to not have a module named like one you are importing, and using a name that is a valid URI to prevent other future problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you use go with modules you could try to run `go mod tidy`

Comment: Didn't work for me.